# Xcode UI Disappeared in El Capitan

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan

Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.0(beta) Navigation Area, Editor Area, Utilty Area are disappeared from window, after I upgraded my Mac from Yosemite to El Capitan. Is there any option to reset xcode window?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using 7.0 beta? 7.1 is out and not in beta? Delete beta versions and install new version of xcode

Comment: Xcode 7.1 has fixed it.